# не могу поменять путь к файлу на диске

Tags: google-colaboratory

уже по разному пыталась записать путь и никак не получается

**from google.colab import drive

drive.mount('/content/drive')

df=pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Content/scrubbed.csv', escapechar='', low_memory=False)**

после многих попыток вставила две первые строчки и тоже ничего